# rich:panelMenu deselect

Tags: jsf-2, menu, richfaces, menuitem

Here's the situation:
I have two code>rich:PanelMenu on the same page menuA and menuB.
When I click an item on menuA the item is selected, fine. Now if I click on a item on menuB the item on menuB is selected, but obviously the selection on menuA is still active.

The question is: How i reset the selection on menuA?

Answer (score 0):

ok, found it! I was looking for `menuA.selectedChild("")` but now apparently is `setValue()`, so `menuA.setValue("")` will do the trick.